# The CSS for #hlogo a has the height 1px too small

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

The bottom of the Stackoverflow logo is being cut off on stackoverflow.com, the height of its container is one pixel too short.

Actual:

[image: actual site]

Expected:

[image: after increasing height]

Comment: Are you viewing this on a Wii?

Comment: No. Chrome/Version 34.0.1847.116 on OS X 10.9.2

Comment: Can't reproduce on Firefox or Safari

Comment: lol, Google Chrome.

Comment: Chrome *is* the bane of my existence when it comes to off-by-one-pixel rendering bugs.

Comment: Hm, I can't reproduce this on Chrome unless I reduce the view size to 90%

Comment: @Tim Stone: Might be an issue specific to Retina display Macs, in which case I'm inclined to classify this as a Chrome bug rather than a miscalculation in the SO stylesheet.

Comment: I've just checked and I do have stackoverflow set to 90% zoom. I'd still file it as a Chrome scaling bug though. If someone wants to write an answer to that effect, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is reproducible on Chrome on retina Mac on the non-default zoom level.

Start at default zoom (command 0) and then make the canvas render at 90% (command -) and you will see the rounding error / cropping. Zooming out to 50% doesn't show this cropping in each successive step. Magnifying the page also doesn't seem to have this artifact.

It might be the CSS is fine and the browser is to blame?