# .bounty-indicator-tab line-height off by a pixel

Tags: bug, design, bountied-tab

I know, I know, this is a really minor issue, but there's a slight discrepancy between the `bounty-indicator-tab` `line-height` (`14px`) and the `#tabs a` `font-size` (`13px`).

This causes (at least in Chrome 34) the `:hover` effect to be off by a pixel as well (which also pushes the page content down by that pixel ... I don't like twitchy pages.):

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229452/the-css-for-hlogo-a-has-the-height-1px-too-small, seems likely chrome specific issue.

Comment: @Amicable Well, unlike that report, I'm not running a Mac (teeheehee) and it's not zoomed.

Comment: In fact - after some more digging - it's a norepro on anything *except* Chrome on 100% scaling.

Comment: IE 11 has the red line [consistently below the grey one](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KaPSC.png), since apparently the `font-weight: 600` is...weightier in IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been resolved.